# Clarification about a point of try-with-resource (JLS)

Tags: java, resources, try-catch

Involves the try-with-resources statement, I have seen a definition of JLS8 [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.20.3.1)

> A try-with-resources statement with a ResourceSpecification clause that declares multiple resources is treated as if it were multiple try-with-resources statements, each of which has a ResourceSpecification clause that declares a single Resource. **When a try-with-resources statement with n Resources (n > 1) is translated, the result is a try-with-resources statement with n-1 Resources**. After n such translations, there are n nested try-catch-finally statements, and the overall translation is complete.

I don't understand why *n-1 resources* instead of *n resources*. Other hand, I found the example [example](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/trywithresources-401775.html#nb3). In this example, the author use try-with-finally instead of using try-with-resources. I don't understant he doesn't use 3 try-catch-finally (he just uses 2)?

Moreover, I also think the try-with-resources with n resources equivalents to n single try-with-resources, e.g:

```
try(R1; R2; R3) = try(R1){try(R2){try(R3)}}}
```

because I think all resources will be created sequentially. And, this try-with-resources above also translate to n try-catch-finally.

Is that all right :) Please help me to clarify :)

Comment: If you translate something with `n` things into something with `n` things, what changes?

Comment: "`try(R1; R2; R3) = try(R1){try(R2){try(R3)}}}`" Yes, this is what the multiple-resource block is equivalent to.

Comment: I believe "translation" refers to the following chapter, where a try-with-resources is translated to a try-catch-finally-block with a close() in the finally block.

If a try-with-multiple-resources is translated, only one of the resources is translated, while the n-1 remaining still form a try-with-multiple-resources.

Which is then further translated until all n resources are translated into "classic" try-catch-finally blocks.

Comment: So, finally, after the try-with-resources is translated "completely", we will have the n try-catch-finally...Moreover, I think this solution is only suitable if we don't throw exceptions (by throws) because when we throw exceptions, we don't need to declare the try-catch-finally...Is that right? @Hok

Comment: One more question: In the example above, I don't see that the author use try-with-resources, he just use try-catch-finally (n-1 try blocks)